# Is there a ServletRequest implementation that does not implement HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, http, servlets

or a `ServletResponse` implementation that does not implement `HttpServletResponse`?

**UPDATE**

Do I always need to detect them in `Filter`? eg

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!(req instanceof HttpServletRequest) || !(resp instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
        // Unexpected
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: and why do you want ?

Comment: Only if you're not extending `HttpServlet`. There could be other kinds, such as `FTPServlet.`

Answer (score 0):

The only one that I know is the [`ServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html) which

> Provides a convenient implementation of the ServletRequest interface
>   that can be subclassed by developers wishing to adapt the request to a
>   Servlet. This class implements the Wrapper or Decorator pattern.
>   Methods default to calling through to the wrapped request object.

So it does not work on its own, as it is just a wrapper for a ServletRequest object that you have to pass to its constructor.

Comment: But we have `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. What is the usage of `ServletRequestWrapper` ?